# Transport class "SMTP" not found in godaddy

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is working in my localhost but when i Upload to godaddy server

**Transport class "SMTP" not found**

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'SMTP',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,

            /************** added code from local**/
             'context' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
  ]
  ],
],
```

Below is the code sending notifications to users

```
**UsersController.php**


**Transport class "SMTP" not found.**

 if($this->Users->save($user)) {

  stack trace =>               $this->getMailer('User')->send('registered', [$user]);
```

}

Comment: I fixed mine by changing 'className' => 'SMTP', to 'className' => 'Mail',

Comment: @distromob The `Mail` transport uses the PHP `mail()` function, which is very different to the `Smtp` (note the lowercase letters) transport.

Comment: @ndm by the way how to fix that one? I just encountered this before but, i just followed what others did.. I just change it to Mail from SMTP which have delayed email. but still I wanted it to use SMTP so that the email will be received directly.

Comment: @distromob Use the correct upper/lowercase letters as shown in my above comment, it's `Smtp`, not `SMTP`.

Comment: @ndm i try to edit but it will not work "Connection refused"

Comment: That's a whole different problem (godaddy gmail/smtp connection refused), for which you can find a lot of topics about here and elsewhere on the net.

Comment: I already tried changing the port but no luck,

Answer (score 0):

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,

     ],
   ],
```

as stated [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.7/app/Config/email.php.default)

Comment: basically it help my problem but their is along delayed like 3mins before receiving the data since not using SMTP